# Custom components to cells in Table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How do i add different componenets to different cells in a tableview. Please note that this is a static table and i have only 4 cells.

The first cell will have an UIImageView.

The other 3 cells will just have labels or textfieilds.

How can i add these components.

Note: This is a storyboard based application and i have added

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *cell;
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell0"];
        cell.profImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"m.jpg"];
        return cell;
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
        cell.lbl.text=@"Hey";
        return cell;
    }
    else if(indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];
        cell.lbl.text=@"Hey 2";
        return cell;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You are doing it rightly, are you getting any problem? But Just remove all the return in if and else block, keep the last one, though your code will work same.

Comment: I get this error ` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'`

Comment: You are missing setup for one extra cell, as there should be an extra `indexPath.row==3` check.

Answer (score 2):

You are having 4 rows in your data source but you are only providing cell object for 3 rows. The last return statement will execute for `indexPath.row==3` and you have not initialised it. Just initialise it for `indexPath.row==3` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyTableViewCell *cell;
if(indexPath.row == 0)
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell0"];
    cell.profImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"m.jpg"];
}
else if(indexPath.row == 1)
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
    cell.lbl.text=@"Hey";
}
else
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];
    cell.lbl.text=@"Hey 2";
}
return cell;
```

The reason that you don't give the default return value to your function and it asks for "If everything goes wrong what will i return?". So you may fix your codes like above and you can try to make like below with the switch - case.

```
TableViewCell *cell;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
  case 0:{
      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell0"];
      cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"m.jpg"];
  }break;
        case 1:{
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell1"];
            cell.myLabel.text=@"Hey";
  }break;
        case 2:{
            cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell2"];
            cell.myLabel.text=@"Hey 2";
  }break;

  default:{
      cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell0"];
      cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"m.jpg"];

}
            break;
    }
    return cell;
```

In above switch-case you may call which cell you want in default statement.